# Sending an array of objects to Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, spring

I am trying to send an array of objects to my spring controller.

First I declare an array in javascript

```
var ar = new Array();
```

Then I create an object with a name and qty

```
var obj = { name: "", qty: "" };
```

The user enters some data into input fields on the html page. When they click the add button, this data will be put into the object.

```
obj = { name: $("#name").val(), qty: $("#qty").val() }
```

Then I take the object and push it into the array I created

```
ar.push(obj);
```

So now I have my array of objects that I want to send to my spring controller.

```
var posting = $.post("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/submitArray.htm", {"ar[]": ar});
```

In my spring controller I request the parameter

```
@RequestParam("ar[]") Object[] objectArray
```

I do get a result back. It's an array of objects, but I do not know how to get the name, or qty from this object.

I have opened the variable in the debugger and it says

```
[[object Object], [object Object]]
```

How do I get the values of name and qty from the object?

Comment: Try [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) instead of `@RequestParam`.

Comment: @31piy I tried `$.post("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/submitArray.htm", {"ar[]": ar});`

and `@RequestBody ReturnObject ar`

I created a ReturnObject class that has the two variables 

`private String name;
  private String qty;`

I got 415 (Unsupported Media Type) in google chrome console after sending the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a java class to define your model object i.e.

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private Double qty;

    //getter setter goes here
}
```

Then Write a rest controller like below:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/submitArray", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity process(@RequestBody List<Model> modelList) {
        for (Model model : modelList) {
            System.out.println(model.getName());
            System.out.println(model.getQty());
        } 
    }
}
```

Now post your javascript array to controller url with header Content-Type "application/json"

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but unfortunately I am using Spring 3.0.6 the following annotations are unavailable from your response `@RestController @PostMapping consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`

We are undergoing some upgrades to our Spring framework as we speak. However, I can use @RequestBody and I have successfully sent back one single object after creating a class that matches that object. I just need to figure out now how to send back an array of these objects, or a list.

Comment: You can ignore those, just implement the model class and add the list with `@RequestBody`